# jQuery wont work when i use append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the glyphicon-cog button clickable

```
 message = new array();
jQuery.fn.update_textarea = function(test) { 
        /* Reset Areas */ 
        $("#articles_textarea").html('');
        $(".test").html(''); 

        for (i=1;i<=test;++i) {       
            if (message[i]) { 
                $("#articles_textarea").append('<h2 class="SettingsHead" data-id="' + i + '"><input type="text" name="sida[]" value="Sida ' + i + '"><div class="Break"></div></h2><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor' + i + '"></textarea>'); 
            } else {
                message[i] = '';
                $(".test").append('<tr><td width="150"><a href="#ShowPage' + i + '" data-toggle="tab" class="ShowPage' + i + '">Sida ' + i + '</a></td><td align="right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Redigera Sidnamnet"></span></tr>');
                if (i == 1) {
                    $("#articles_textarea").append('<div class="tab-pane active" id="ShowPage' + i + '"><h2 class="SettingsHead" data-id="' + i + '"><input type="text" name="sida[]" class="testing" value="Sida ' + i + '"><div class="Break"></div></h2><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor' + i + '"></textarea></div>'); 
                } else { 
                    $("#articles_textarea").append('<div class="tab-pane" id="ShowPage' + i + '"><h2 class="SettingsHead" data-id="' + i + '"><input type="text" name="sida[]" value="Sida ' + i + '"><div class="Break"></div></h2><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor' + i + '"></textarea></div>'); 
                }
            }
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' + i );
        }
    }
```

But when i use this code

```
$(".glyphicon-cog").click(function() { alert('y'); });
```

Nothing happends, it's like im not clicking the button.. Is this because of the append or is it because of something else?

Anyways hope any of you people out there can find the problem and help me find a solution

Comment: Where does `message` magically come from? Is it really so non-standard it has 1-based indexes?

Comment: Are you sure that the dom element is created before you actually attach an event to it ?

Comment: Sorry missed that part i update it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `.on` if you are appending the selector.

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-cog', function() { alert('y'); });
```

Comment: I think this code does the same as his code. Did you mean to recommend using event delegation?

Comment: it should be e.g: `$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-cog', function() { alert('y'); });`

Comment: @A.Wolff Wouldn't they both do the same thing?

Comment: @KyleNeedham one is delegated to document level, it is equivalent to live(). The other is equivalent to bind()